# No resource or method named `windows_zipfile' for `Chef::Recipe "default"'

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

When I try to run a simple unzip recipe on windows environment I am getting the below error:

```
No resource or method named `windows_zipfile' for `Chef::Recipe "default"'
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

This resource is defined in the [windows cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/windows#windows_zipfile), not in Chef core itself.

Thus, in order to use it, you have to declare the windows cookbook as a dependency of your cookbook and upload it to the Chef server (or your cookbooks directory when running with chef solo).